# MySQL - How to perform operation on entire column?

Tags: mysql, database, shell

For instance, say that I have a column containing all integer values {1, 6, 9, 5, ...} and so on. If I want to perform a mathematical operation on each value in the column, what is the best way to do this?

Edit: I am looking for an example query, particularly.

Comment: The question is not clear... what do you want to do with the results? (select them? store the values in the same/another column?)

Comment: I would like to replace each value with the result of the operation performed on that value.

Comment: You just leave off the `where` clause... many people have done this by accident meaning to update a single record!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column = column+1
```

Updates all the `column` fields increasing the values by one.

Answer (score 2):

You did not specified that which type of operation you want to do.

So for different operation you do following things as per it.

For Addtion :

```
UPDATE tablename SET column = column+value
```

For Subtraction:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column = column-value
```

For multiplication:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column = column*value
```

For division:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column = column/value
```

For Modulo:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column = column%value
```

I hope you will get solution.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
UPDATE myfile SET MyFIeld = MyField + 20
```

Docs:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

The assigned value can include functions, columns and other expression elements.

Please note: It's not typically advisable to do an UPDATE on all rows. Usually, you'll want to add a WHERE clause to limit the operation to only certain rows.